# Catch PhantomJs by Fiddler

Tags: .net, selenium, proxy, phantomjs, fiddler

Sometimes, during normal run I want to see what data are passing from site to my .NET application. I use Fiddler for it. Normally it catch all requests and responds. Except Selenium2 + PhantomJs. I understand, that I can manually write proxy to PhantomJs arguments. But in this way I need to run Fiddler or other proxy all time. I don't want this. Also I don't see a way of dynamic set up proxy for PhantomJs during execution. Only from constructor. 
So is there is any way to catch PhantomJs traffic, without setting up proxy options for PhantomJs? Maybe with other web debugger, not Fiddler?

Answer (score 1):

You can, of course, capture traffic from PhantomJS using NetMon or Wireshark, but that's a goofy way of going about things that means you won't see HTTPS traffic and so on.

Why not just detect whether Fiddler is running and conditionally set the proxy only if it is?

(It's certainly *implied* that PhantomJS can automatically use or not use a proxy based on the system proxy settings; e.g. https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10580)